# Prevent The User From Keeping A Key Pressed Down

Tags: c++, qt, key

So in my application I am checking to see what key the user has pressed. Dont want the user to be able to hold down the space bar which in turn creates multiple objects. I want the user to have to be able to release the space bar before an object is created. What I was using before is keyPressEvent then I tried this -> which I thought would work but didn't

```
void MyItem::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)


 if(event->key()== Qt::Key_Space){

           //create object and display

 }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to how to make sure the user has to lift their finger of the key pad thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
void MainWindow::keyReleaseEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    if((event->key() == Qt::Key_Space)&&(!event->isAutoRepeat()))
    {
       //create object and display
    }
}
```